# In a PHP webpage, reading text from an external PHP to make updating content across pages easy

Tags: php, html

I'm writing a small website that has multiple pages. I'd like to have the same footers on each page, but I don't want to manually update 10 pages of HTML everyday. I'd like to put a PHP call to an external file in each HTML page (now .php pages, thanks to @br14np) so that when I update the PHP file, all the pages - when loaded - will show the same footer text.

```
<p><?php footertext.php ?></p>
```

is my wild guess at loading the content in the file of the afformentioned name but to no avail. (In footertext.php the code is: `<?php print("Test numba one") ?>`).

How can I go about doing this? I'd prefer an answer involving PHP.

**UPDATE:**

This is the exact code I'm using. Everything is in the same directory.

Main File:

```
<html>
    <head> 
    </head>

    <body>
        <p> Content: <?php include "footertext.php ?></p>
    </body>

</html>
```

Footer Content:

`echo 'Test numba TWO!';`

Comment: If you bothered to Google it, you'd find this is one of the very first things one should learn when coming across php. `<? include 'footertext.php' ?>`

Comment: The file youre calling from must be a `.php` file **or** the server must be configured to handle `.html` or whatever extension as php.

Comment: @andy Thanks I did a lot of Googling (for example [like this](http://goo.gl/ng3Ro)) but I guess I didn't know exactly what terms to search for. Thanks for the answer though +1

Comment: What sort of environment are you running this website in? Are you running it on a web server that's configured for php? Is it running from your machine?

Comment: @br14np I'm using WAMP

Comment: I think there may be more to the story here. If you're still not having any luck using the `include` code, there's likely something missing elsewhere. `include` is typically very straightforward to implement. I know that's not helpful :-\ but I don't feel that we can help you with the info provided. You could try something like adding some plain html content into the footertext.php file for debugging this issue

Comment: @br14np I've updated it to the exact code I'm testing with, based on responses here and content on W3Schools

Comment: @Imray I've posted a response to your update

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED: Turns out, I had been opening the folder directly from the `www` folder in `wamp` instead of loading it through `localhost`, which is why the PHP wasn't loading. Your answer to use include was correct! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `include` function. Just give it the path to your file. Example:

```
<?php include "footertext.php"; ?>
```

There are a few other functions that do similar things, such as `require_once()`. You can read more about that [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp).

**Response to update**

You're missing closing quotation marks after `"footertext.php`. Another tip that may help this situation is to turn on php error reporting. This will display any syntax or other errors on your page. Just insert the following code at the very top of your pages:

```
<?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
?>
```

Also make sure you have opening and closing php tags (`<?php ... ?>`) in your footertext.php file.

Comment: Make sure that the file with this `include` function is also a .php file. You can't embed php code in normal .html files

Comment: It is, my file is called footertext.php and they are in the same directory

Comment: But what is the name of the file that you are putting this `include "footertext.php"` into? You mentioned you're using HTML files in your question. You must use .php files for all of the pages that you want to include footertext.php into

Comment: After Update: Still not working, and when I put the error reporting code at the top of the page, the web page in Chrome shows up as the entire text of the document as if it was a .txt file

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED: Turns out, I had been opening the folder directly from the `www` folder in `wamp` instead of loading it through `localhost`, which is why the PHP wasn't loading. Your answer to use include was correct! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The best fit solution for your query is *include* or *require* functions of php. now you need to identify which one out of those are your choices based on their functional behavior.

## PHP include and require Statements

In PHP, you can insert the content of one PHP file into another PHP file before the server executes it.

The include and require statements are used to insert useful codes written in other files, in the flow of execution.

**Include and require are identical, except upon failure:**

- require will produce a fatal error (E_COMPILE_ERROR) and stop the
- include will only produce a warning (E_WARNING) and the script will continue

So, if you want the execution to go on and show users the output, even if the include file is missing, use include. Otherwise, in case of FrameWork, CMS or a complex PHP application coding, always use require to include a key file to the flow of execution. This will help avoid compromising your application's security and integrity, just in-case one key file is accidentally missing.

Including files saves a lot of work. This means that you can create a standard header, footer, or menu file for all your web pages. Then, when the header needs to be updated, you can only update the header include file.

## Syntax

> ***include 'filename.ext';***
>   or
>   ***require 'filename';***

You may like to go through the details of
[Include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php),
[Require](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php),
[Require_once](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) &
[Include_once](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php).

Enjoy!
Anand Chavan

Comment: This is pretty much copied straight from W3Schools. Can you give an example? The W3Schools method is not working for me...

Comment: @Imray : Once you know the appropriate track, you should be able to R&D the demonstration stuff.

However for your simplicity I am providing you the link. where author has done exactly what you are looking for

http://buildinternet.com/2009/12/using-the-php-include-function-to-template-faster/